# checking on remote applications

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I want to run and check on apps (like rtorrent) running on server via ssh.  I'd prefer not to use background/foreground stuff.  What I really want to do is have a screen session on this server all the time and attach/detach/reattach remotely, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick rundown, but a screen tutorial will get you farther:

'screen' invokes it, and you use ctrl-a then d to disconnect (and leave it running)

'screen -ls' lists open sessions

'screen -r' connects to a disconnected session.

'screen -x' connects to an active session (if you want to run two terminals at once)

Here's a screen tutorial:
http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935